# c# Windows 8: Combobox selected item

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem

I have a ComboBox filled with the names of different movies. (e.g Skyfall)
When I select 'Skyfall' in the ComboBox I would like to change my Image to the logo of the movie (Images/Skyfall.png) The logo always have the same name as the Title of the movie + .png
How could I do this?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: are you referring with window forms? WPF, asp.net or etc?

Comment: LogoTeam1.Source =  "Images/Jpl" + Team1.SelectedValue.ToString() + ".png"; Doesn't work.

Comment: It is an Windows 8 Project

Comment: What type of control is `LogoTeam1`

Comment: LogoTeam1 is an Image Control

Answer (score 0):

Use `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event. Set an array of image paths with name `ImagePathArray` and store all your paths as string in it.
 In the `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` change your `picturebox.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(ImagePathArray[ComboBox.SelectedIndex]);`